# jmeter hangs up and won't return

Tags: httprequest, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am running 340 concurrent users to load test on server using jmeter.

But on most of the cases jmeter hangs up and won' t return, even if I try to close the connection it just hangs up. and eventually I have to close the application.

Any idea how to check what is holding the requests and how to check the requests sent by jmeter and find the bottleneck.

Got the following message on closing the thread

```
Shutting down thread please be patient message
```

Comment: Please show test plan summary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've hit this several times over the past few years. In each of my cases (may not be in your's) the issue was with the Load Balance (F5) I was sending my traffic through. Basically a property called OneConnect was holding the connections in a time-wait state and never killing the connection.

Run a pack tool like wireshark and see what's happening with the requests.

Answer (score 1):

Try distributed testing, 340 concurrent users is not a big deal, but still you can try if that decreases your pain. Also take a look at the following link:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean

Answer (score 0):

First check you script is ok with one user.
Ensure you use assertions.

Then run you test following jmeter best practices:

- no gui
- no costly listeners

You should then be able to see in csv output the longest request and be able to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem before when I run my JMeter on my laptop(Core 2 Duo 1.5Ghz) it always hang-up in the middle of the processing. I tried to run on another pc which is more powerful than my laptop and its works now smoothly. Therefore, JMeter will run effectively if your pc or laptop has a better specs.

Note: It is also advisable to run your JMeter in non-gui mode.
Example to run JMeter in Linux box:

```
$ ./jmeter -t test.jmx -n -l /Users/home/test.jtl
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the

> one or more test threads won't exit

because of a firewall blocking some requests. So I had to leap in the firewalls timeout for all blocked request... then it returned.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error probably because JVM is not capable of running so many threads. If you take a look at your terminal, you will see the exception you get:

> Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. See log file for details.

You can solve this by doing [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) and have multiple clusters running, instead of one.